# Определить MAC-адрес по заданному IP

Tags: c#

Как можно по заданному IP определить его МАС-адрес в сети на языке С#?

Comment: Только учтите, @Pentium, все данные Вам здесь способы определения MAC работают **только** для IP в локальной сети (т.к. основаны на ARP).

Для интересующих Вас DDoS (по предыдущим вопросам и безусловно с целью защиты) это означает, что злоумышленник должен работать локально, а не из-за роутера.

--

Опять непонятный мне минус вопроса (и без объяснения причин)

Answer (score 4):

```
public static string ConvertIpToMAC(IPAddress ip)
{
    byte[] addr = new byte[6];
    int length = addr.Length;

    // TODO: Проверить, что результат - NO_ERROR
    SendARP(ip.GetHashCode(), 0, addr, ref length);

    return BitConverter.ToString(addr, 0, 6);
}

[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int SendARP(int DestinationIP, int SourceIP, [Out] byte[] pMacAddr, ref int PhyAddrLen);
```

[SendARP function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв....

Comment: А как можно узнать не свой Мак адрес а удаленного хоста одной локальной сети (своей) введя его IP?

Answer (score 3):

Ответы:

- [Get MAC Address in C# from IP Address/Hostname](http://mycomponent.blogspot.com/2009/05/get-mac-address-in-c-from-ip.html)
- [How do I obtain the physical (MAC) address of an IP address using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187894/how-do-i-obtain-the-physical-mac-address-of-an-ip-address-using-c)

Собственно, код из второй ссылки:

```
IPAddress dst = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.1"); // Требуемый IP адрес

byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
uint macAddrLen = (uint)macAddr.Length;

if (SendARP(BitConverter.ToInt32(dst.GetAddressBytes(), 0), 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen) != 0)
     throw new InvalidOperationException("SendARP failed.");

string[] str = new string[(int)macAddrLen];
for (int i=0; i<macAddrLen; i++)
     str[i] = macAddr[i].ToString("x2");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(":", str));
```

Comment: @Olter, а Вам не приходило в голову, что если человек **задает вопрос не русскоязычном сайте**, то у него м.б. проблемы с английским ?

Comment: @avp, попробуйте набрать в гугле такой запрос:
определить МАС-адрес по IP "c#"
Я уверен, что ответ вы найдете.

Comment: @avp, не всегда. Мне, например, более комфортно задавать и отвечать на вопросы на родном языке, хотя мог и бы на SO это сделать без проблем. Да и потом - там же код, а он на всех языках одинаков.